# Returning location not value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList made up of objects from another class.  I am having trouble accessing values from the ArrayList.  I have populated my ArrayList, and have written the below to try and retrieve specific elements.  However, I keep getting Player@4f2456 returned instead of the player's name.

```
public void playerName(int index)
{
    Player player = players.get(index);
    System.out.println(player);
}
```

I can return the list of players using this:

```
public void listAllPlayerNames()
{
    for (Player players : players)
        System.out.println (players.getPlayerName());
}
```

But can't ask for a specific playername to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You played yourself. :)

You're overloading two variables with the same name.  I'm surprised the compiler doesn't warn you about this.

Instead of this:

```
for (Player players : players)
    System.out.println (players.getPlayerName());
```

This:

```
for (Player player : players)
    System.out.println (player.getPlayerName());
```

Also for this function:

```
public void playerName(int index)
{
    Player player = players.get(index);
    System.out.println(player);
}
```

You are printing the literal object identifier for "player" instead of the player's name.  Isn't this what you want?

```
public void playerName(int index)
{
    Player player = players.get(index);
    System.out.println(player.getPlayerName());
}
```

Comment: It is not overloading.  It is is shadowing.  It is permitted because this is a local variable declaration shadowing a field.  It *might* be worth the compiler warning you about this, but it is certainly not a compilation error.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm very new to this, I don't know why I thought I was supposed to do it the way I had it.  You guys rock, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line will print your reference to your `player` object. That's why you get `Player@4f2456`.

```
System.out.println(player);
```

This is the implementation of above method:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}

public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So, in order to print `player` information correctly using `System.out.println`, you have to override the `toString` method in this class.

```
public class Player {
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return playerName;
   }
}
```